# Not sure how to handle multiple timed threads in a Windows service

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services

This is my first time putting together a Windows service application and I've been doing a bit of reading on different approaches to running multiple tasks in some manner of timed intervals.  One being once a day and another every 1 min.

What I had concluded to do was use the TimedCallBack and System.threating.timer timer.

Non-elegant example

```
private void DailyTask(object state) {
  //do something daily
}

private void IntervalTask(object state) {
  //do something else
}

private void OnStart() {
  TimedCallBack dailyTcb = DailyTask;
  TimedCallBack intervalTcb = IntervalTask;
  System.Threading.Timer dailyTimer = new Timer(dailyTcb, null, 0, 86400000);
  System.Threading.Timer intervalTimer = new Timer(intervalTcb, null, 0, 60000);
}

private void OnStop() {
  intervalTimer.Dispose();
  dailyTimer.Dispose();
}
```

**Questions**

1) does the timer start the clock following the completion  of the task? Which would slowly cause it to creep past a day if every time it ran it took some amount of time to complete?  Which I would assume then that I would need to determine how long it took to 
run minus 24hrs?

2) is this a perfectly fine approach for 2 simple tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer does not wait until after completion of the task to restart the timer. For example, if you set your timer to 20 milliseconds and the callback took more than 20 milliseconds to process, you would get another tick before the first one finished.

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your idea. However, if that's all your service is doing (i.e. just sitting there, waiting to fire once per interval), you might consider making it a simple console mode program and using scheduled tasks to execute it. Check out Windows Task Scheduler and the schtasks command line tool.